# PhoneGap App Customisation via config file

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building a PhoneGap app that can be used by multiple companies who can skin and customise it in a number of ways eg. putting their company name in certain parts, theme colours etc.

Is there any easy way to do this through PhoneGap? I only need to deploy to Android for now.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new task in a local Gruntfile.js that copies files your custom files into the project

```
grunt.initConfig({
  selectBranch: {
    branch1: {
      src: 'css/styleBranch1.js',
      dest: 'dest/style.css',
    },
    branch2: {
      src: 'css/styleBranch2.js',
      dest: 'dest/style.css',
    },
  }
});
```

In the same directory execute "grunt selectBranch branch1" so copy your files before your build task